# Playing a video from res/raw on Android Wear

Tags: android, file, assets, wear-os, android-videoview

More specific: I am trying to load a video from res/raw with jcodec's FrameGrab.

FrameGrab requires a SeekableBiteChannel, so a File will work.

How can I get a video file from assets as a File?

I cannot put the video on the sd-card or anything similar, I am developing for Android Wear.

EDIT:

```
String videoPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.hyperlapse2;
mVideoTestUri = Uri.parse(videoPath);
Log.d("VideoPlayer", "Video uri is " + mVideoTestUri);
File file = new File(videoPath);
Log.d("VideoPlayer", "Video file is " + file+", "+file.getName()+", "+file.getAbsolutePath()+", "+file.length());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference a File in raw folder in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752417/how-to-reference-a-file-in-raw-folder-in-android)

Comment: Its not a duplicate, that question handles reading text files, I am reading a video

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I made it work. I don't know if this is something Android Wear specific or a bug, but it turns out that

```
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
File file = new File(path);
```

does not give access to the file on Android Wear devices.

Instead one has to convert the file into a temp file first:

```
InputStream ins = MainActivityBackup.this.getResources().openRawResource (R.raw.hyperlapse2);
File tmpFile = null;
OutputStream output;

try {
    tmpFile = File.createTempFile("video","mov");
    output = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

    final byte[] buffer = new byte[102400];
    int read;

    while ((read = ins.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    ins.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And then it can be loaded into a videoView

```
mVideoView.setVideoPath(tmpFile.getPath());
```

Provided you are using your own video decoder or a library like ffmpeg or vitamio, since Android Wear does not support native video playback yet.

Answer (score 0):

Place the video in the resource directory under a folder called raw.

```
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
File file = new File(path);

VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
view.start();
```

Comment: maybe refresh the page, its there

Comment: I tested the same code and even though the file length is incorrect the file plays correctly in a videoview.

Comment: Did you get a file length of 0 as well or some different length alltogether?

Comment: My file length returned 0.  The file name returned as a random int which was assigned in resource creation.

Comment: It's weird, I try to read it with jcodec but it keeps giving me a java.io.FileNotFoundException: /2130968577: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Just for the sake of testing the above code, I would add a VideoView to your activity and see if the video plays.  I'll amend by above code.

Comment: Its not possible to play the video natively on Android Wear, because it doesnt support video, only audio, thats why I need jcodec.

Comment: Ah i see.  My best guess then is that the video isn't supported by the codec.  The above code does work in standard android.  That's probably all the help I am going to be.  Good Luck.

Comment: I made it work with some workarounds, I posted the answer below.