# Android, How to read from a Json in the raw folder

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to open a Json file which is in the raw folder inside res 
[My file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYMXc.png)

But it fails with every method I have tried, I just need the string since I can parse `Json` `Strings` already.

This is my `Json` reader

```
public class Parser extends Activity {
    public String getStringFromJson(String path) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(path)));
            String temp;
            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(temp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close(); // stop reading
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

It fails in the line:

`br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(path)));`

And this is what **logcat** said:

```
02-03 10:44:13.440 2374-2374/com.example.ealcazar.kolibry E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ealcazar.kolibry/com.example.ealcazar.kolibry.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.BufferedReader.close()' on a null object reference
```

is there an easier way to read a `Json`? what Path should I use when trying to access my file in the `RAW folder`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: My problem was that I was confusing the res folder with the assets folder, and also I was getting a wrong context.

I created an assets folder in Android Studio and also got the context from my mainActivity by declaring it as static and assign it in onCreate (MainActivity.context.getResources)

Answer (score 6):

Replace these line of code

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(path)));
```

With these

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json));//Here json is the name of the file which is placed inside the RAW folder in yours resource
```

Comment: `Parser.this.getResources()` => `getResources()`  ... you don't need `Parser.this`

Comment: Sometime it throws the exception there @Selvin .. I used the ClassName.getResoure() instead of getResource() method..any ways thanks for suggestion :)

Comment: What you think.. Is it bad practice to use the CLASSNAME.this before access the resources??

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem isn't fixed, at least now it seems to know where the file is, the crash is still in the same line and the logcat is now :02-03 11:05:38.740 12864-12864/com.example.ealcazar.kolibry E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ealcazar.kolibry/com.example.ealcazar.kolibry.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.BufferedReader.close()' on a null object reference

Comment: it is not about resources ... `getResources()` is a method ... like many others ... there is no need for Class.this.method() if "you are in the Class"

Comment: ok thanks a lot @Selvin ...for yours useful comments...I am editing my answer.. :)

Comment: @EnriqueAlcazar .. you have to make check before  br.close that if(br!=null){ br.close}

Comment: @EnriqueAlcazar .. Is it workable for you ?? .Or you getting some error or exception

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha it is still not working, your idea was good, but if that's happening it means the br is empty and that means the line is still failing. the logical i now saying 02-03 11:23:49.820 21788-21788/com.example.ealcazar.kolibry E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ealcazar.kolibry/com.example.ealcazar.kolibry.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: @EnriqueAlcazar try these lines of code on link.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15934525/3946958 .. and let me know in case of concern

Comment: If it is workable for you than plz accept it once :)

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha still more exceptions :java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference I think It's not finding my Json, but is there this is te code  `InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(
                    getResources().getIdentifier(Path,
                            "raw", getPackageName()));
            strJson = readTextFile(ins);` and Path is test which is the name of my file

Comment: please check these links..it might be helpful for you  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15934525/3946958   http://stackoverflow.com/a/9752719/3946958    and last one   http://www.41post.com/3985/programming/android-loading-files-from-the-assets-and-raw-folders