# How can I import, and use txt file in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import, assets

I've tried, searched a lot of things here, but non of those seem to work. (The file has 5000 rows) I keep getting error massages.
For example with AssetManager: Cannot resolve method 'getAssets()' -> and in the code getAssets is red.

```
private static InputStream getReadTextFromAssets() throws IOException {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream file = assetManager.open("tryToRead.txt");
    return file;
}
```

Comment: If it is in non activity class then you need to use specific context or use `getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for getting files from assets folder. So instead I created a `raw` folder inside `res` directory, then copied my files inside`raw` folder. Now getting the files from `raw` folder was very easy. See below link

[How to read file from res/raw by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912825/how-to-read-file-from-res-raw-by-name)

You can also see below link if you want to stick with `asset` folder.

[How to reference a File in raw folder in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752417/how-to-reference-a-file-in-raw-folder-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Method `getAssets()` is accessable via instance of `Resources` class,

pass that as argument to your method:

```
private static InputStream getReadTextFromAssets(Resources myRes) throws IOException {}
```

and use it to call `getAssets()`

```
myRes.getAssets()
```

and for using your method, pass `Resources` when invoking method

```
InputStram is = getReadTextFromAssets(getResources());
```

Again, `getResources()` needs `Context` class [Activity]
or an instance of `Context` obtained from an Activity.